# AWS S3 max number of buckets for IAM user or Root account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

The AWS S3 documentation says:

> A bucket is owned by the AWS account that created it. Each AWS account can own up to 100 buckets at a time.

Would "AWS account" in this case refer to the Root Account or the IAM user that created the bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the root account. IAM user is not an account just a user role defined for the account.